# How to unlock a file taht was opened/edited/saved then re-opened using iTHit WebDAV Ajax library and iTHit Server?

Tags: ithit-webdav-server, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I have a user who gotten a word file locked (attempting to edit again displays a message in word that the file is locked by another user) after editing and saving...I restarted IIS then the user's PC then the web server...the file is still locked...How can we unlock this file?  How can we prevent this from happening...
We are using iTHit Ajax library v1.8.0.1342 and IT Hit WebDav Server v3.7.1780

Comment: Tested this morning after about 12 hours of no activity on the file and it is unlocked…How does the locking work?  Where is the lock stored? Can it be deleted without waiting? Is there a timer that unlocks a file after a certain amount of time?  Is it configurable?  I will be having the user try to find the exact sequence that causes the file to be locked but any information on how/when the lock is handled would help.

Comment: Checking the IIS log...last night the LOCK had a status of 423 and this morning the status was 200...

Comment: Who is issuing the LOCKS/Options/Propfind/Head/Get commands?  iTHit server, iTHit Ajax Library or Word?  How are the locks supposed to be released (unlock)?

Comment: Your question has some formatting issues. Please edit it using the "edit" link to add all relevant information in the question itself, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Per iTHit...The lock is requested by the client applictaion, typically by Microsoft Office. The client application specifies the lock period in its request. The server can either issue the lock for the specified period or for any other period it wants. The lock time is passed back to the client. In your server implementation you can program the lock time in ILock.Lock method implementation.
I used Fiddler and found that Word and Excel specified 3600 seconds and the function on the server adds that to the current GMT time for the lock expiration..